# Bones are deforming the mesh at different rates. Is there a way to fix this?

Tags: mesh, rigging

When trying to control the eyelid and eyelashes mesh (both are part of the same mesh although the eyelashes are not attached to the rest of the head). Moving the gaze bone up causes the eyelids to move at the appropriate speed, but the eyelashes move at a different speed and don't stay where they need to be.[image]

Eyelid deform bones are circled in red. These bones are restricted to X rotation only.

[image]

After changing the gaze bone to make the character look up, eye lashes detach.
[image: Eye lashes no longer attached to eye lids]

I have tried weight painting the eyelashes but it doesn't make a difference unless the weight is set to zero and then the eyelashes don't move at all.

Is there a way to fix this?

Link to the .blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bcrigg4d4nrbwv/Blenderman%20-%20Working%20On%20Eye%20Control.blend?dl=0

Comment: I think the weight paint of concerned vertices are sharing another vertex group's weight. Can you share the .blend file so we can take a closer look?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4bcrigg4d4nrbwv/Blenderman%20-%20Working%20On%20Eye%20Control.blend?dl=0
Here is the .blend file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the eyelashes are not included in the head bone's vertex group :

- Select the armature and switch to pose mode
- Select the head mesh and switch to weight painting mode
- Select the head bone and you'll see that :

[image]

You just have to paint the whole head mesh vertices for the head bone's vertex group with the same weight color, including the eyelashes, and you'll be saved !