# Rigging problem with mesh body in pose mode

Tags: rigging, bones

[image]

This is the problem happening while I am rotating the left arm bones in pose mode as you can see in the picture.All the vertex groups are correctly weighted and parent with the bones.Even rotating bones will be transforming the left arm but not exact position with bone position.

[image]

Now look the vertex weight paint it is showing correct weight color to move with bones.

Even though left arm is moving not according to bone position.

[male_body_with_bones blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4jU1_T9N6ZmcTRDX2kyalVWdnM/edit?usp=sharing)

Please help.Thank you in advanced

Comment: This is the same problem as in [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16053/bones-are-deforming-the-mesh-at-different-rates-is-there-a-way-to-fix-this). See my answer. Here, the problem is that the arm's vertices are included into the "spine" bone's vertex group. Remove them from any other group than "biceps" or "arm", and everything should be fine.

Comment: But i am already having different vertex group for each bone,u can see that in my blender file or the 2nd screen shot i have attached.clearly it can be seen by weight paint that bicep and arm vertex group is only included in bicep group.

Comment: Sorry but you're wrong... If you select the "spine" vertex group while in weight paint mode, you'll see that the arms are red, too. Which you need to avoid.

Comment: many many thanks Polosson, u r absolutely right I got the solution now I can step forward with my project. Again THANKS