# Rigging eyelashes (object, not hair)

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm trying to rig a face and I made seperate objects for eyelashes, as the character is going to be stylized. Eyelashes are made using basic mesh with added subdivision -> shrinkwrap -> solidify

how can I make the eyelash mesh precisely follow the eyelid?

Any help is much appreciated.[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16053/bones-are-deforming-the-mesh-at-different-rates-is-there-a-way-to-fix-this/16054#16054

Comment: Oh, that actually answers my question perfectly. Thank you!